# SSL input filter read failed

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, openssl

Am using apache-httpd-2.4.3 in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga).

When I am trying to hit browser using URL, getting this messages in webserver's ssl_error_log:

```
[Tue Feb 25 16:26:35.007452 2014] [ssl:info] [pid 11111:tid 1212121212] (70014)End of file found: [client 172.16.26.217:50189] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed. [Tue Feb 25 16:26:55.839759 2014] [ssl:info] [pid 22222:tid 1414141414] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 172.16.26.217:50202] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
```

Comment: This [ServerFault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/633787/ssl-input-filter-read-failed-apache-and-443) discusses this but doesn't really solve it for all scenarios. I have multiple VirtualHosts and multiple certificates on the same IP using SNI. It should work, and it seems to work fine in the browser. But there are all these info warnings!